Motivation for Nets in topology
In Folland chapter 4 he provided an example for why sequential convergence doesn't play central role in general topological spaces as it does in metric spaces. he said consider $C^{\mathbb{R}}$, space of all complex-valued function on R. with the product topology(i.e. the topology of pointwise convergence) and its subspace $C({\mathbb{R}})$. on one hand if $\{f_n\} \subset C(\mathbb{R}) \quad \text{and} \quad f_n \to f \quad \text{pointwise,}$  then $f$ is borel measurable but not necessarily continous. I understand this point and the argument it said that space of continous function is dense. but why sequence is not enough to reach all the limit points of this space? we know every convergent sequence either converges to continuous or non-continuous function and those limit functions are member of the $C^{\mathbb{R}}$, why he said there are some limit points that cannot be reached by sequences in $C({\mathbb{R}})$? I think this is not a good example for motivating us to learn nets and cocountable topology is a better example for that.

I agree that cocountable topology seems an easier example, though $\mathbb{C}^\mathbb{R}$ does have the benefit of being Hausdorff while the cocountable topology (on any uncountable set) is not. And $\mathbb{C}^\mathbb{R}$ does work, as continuous functions are dense in $\mathbb{C}^\mathbb{R}$ but sequential limits of continuous functions are Borel, and not all functions are Borel-measurable.

Though, an easier example in $\mathbb{C}^\mathbb{R}$ might be taking $A$, the set of indicator functions of countable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Then the constant function $1$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is in the closure of $A$, but no sequence in $A$ can reach $1$. (In fact, $A$ is already sequentially closed - any convergent sequence in $A$ converges to elements of $A$.)

thank you so much! I got the point!

Folland did not directly state that some limit points of $C(\mathbb{R})$ are not pointwise limits of elements of $C(\mathbb{R})$. Although this is indeed true, the main point to be taken from this example is that there are certain fundamental topological properties which cannot, in general, be characterised alone by sequences and their limits. In fact, Folland brings up this very point himself earlier on in the book within the following quote.

… First countable spaces have the pleasant property that such things as closure and continuity can be characterised in terms of sequential convergence - which is not the case in more general spaces, as we shall see. For example:
4.6 Proposition. If $X$ is first countable and $A \subset X$, then $x\in \overline{A}$ iff there is a sequence $\{ x_{j} \}$ in $A$ that converges to $x$.
...

Here Folland is mentioning a way to characterise to the closure of a subset of a first countable space using sequences. The example you are asking about illustrates that this very property does not hold for all topological spaces. Considering that sequences of functions have been considered all over the place in the previous chapters, I would suggest that this provides a clear motivation for introducing nets. There is a similar post here with two answers that you may find helpful for more of an explanation.
For your main question, you asked why you cannot use pointwise limits of sequences in $C(\mathbb{R})$ to obtain all elements of $\mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{R}}$. All you have to do is put together some results you are already aware of.
Claim. Every non-Borel measurable function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ satisfies the following two properties.

The function $f$ is a limit point of $C(\mathbb{R})$ as a subset of $\mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{R}}$ equipped with the topology of pointwise convergence.

There is no sequence of functions in $C(\mathbb{R})$ which converges to $f$ pointwise.


Proof. Because $C(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{R}}$ we have that $\mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{R}}$ is equal to the union of $C(\mathbb{R})$ and the limit points of $C(\mathbb{R})$. Since $f\not\in C(\mathbb{R})$ it follows that $f$ is a limit point of $C(\mathbb{R})$. Now suppose for a contradiction there is a sequence in $C(\mathbb{R})$ which converges to $f$ pointwise. Then $f$ must be Borel measurable since a pointwise limit of continuous functions is Borel measurable which leads to a contradiction. Hence there is no such sequence.

thank you so much for your great explanation!
